# prevent uploading large image files in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website written in asp.net MVC and C#.We have a functionality to upload photos and  i am using jquery.form.js to do the image submit since we have to show a preview of the image as well.

I would like to prevent the users uploading images with size more than 2 mb.
Is this possible ? We are not allowed to use flash or silverlight.

Currently i am checking the ContentLength property inside the post method and showing an error
if the size is greater than 2mb.

I was wondering if its possible to check in any other way ? I am concerned if the user tries to upload a 20 MB image and that will slow down the whole server ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maximum size of a request in `web.config`:

```
<configuration> 
    <system.web> 
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" /> 
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

You'll then need to catch and respond to the corresponding "max request length exceeded" exception.

Comment: Thanks ! I have already added the settings in web.config. I was trying to catch the error before the request is completed.Otherwise if somebody tries to upload a file of 20 MB or 30mb size, i will have to wait until the whole file is processed before i throw an error.

Comment: how can i catch the max request length exceeded error in the controller ?